# Linux shuts down my pc's lan port so I am unable to use wakeonlan, works with windows

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, shutdown

I got the Asus mini pc pn51-s1 with the 5700u cpu. https://www.asus.com/displays-desktops/mini-pcs/pn-series/mini-pc-pn51-s1/techspec/

I turned on the bios function wake on pcie card which allows me to send a signal remotely to turn on the computer.

I tested it with windows 10 and 11 and the wake on lan works fine. When the computer is shutdown or freshly plugged in and power switch turned on, you can see that the lan port lights are on. I am able to wake on lan using the app or any other computer on the network with the etherwake command.

I am able to shutdown remotely or locally, and I can see the lan port lights are on. I turn it back on remotely after that using etherwake or some other program.

However, I tried installing debian, dietpi and arch linux on it and I am unable to get wake on lan to work.

It works if I just plug the mini pc into the power and turn on the switch, but if I power it off, it just stays off. I can see that the lan port led lights are shutoff when I poweroff using debian or dietpi, but they stay on with windows.

I have tried dietpi with my thinkpad x260 and it works as it's supposed to, I can poweroff and on remotely.

But with this new asus mini pc, I can do it. I don't understand why the lan port goes off during shutdown. Am I missing a driver or something?

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I can enable this feature? I think linux doesn't shutdown something properly and the lan card shutsdown fully.

I get the same error in all the linux operating systems,

```
 ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

Comment: Edit your question to describe how the error *`ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)`* manifests and its impact on the system (e.g. does it interrupt boot?).  *`It works if I just plug the mini pc into the power and turn on the switch, but if I power it off, it just stays off.`* Edit your question to clarify if can't power up from the power switch after a shutdown.  Also what is plugged into what ports.

Comment: Can you pick one Linux variant to troubleshoot in.

Comment: I found a solution, https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan

It works for me.


Add an interface config file /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0 (or modify the global interface config file /etc/network/interfaces):

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        ethernet-wol g

Activate it:

sudo reboot

Comment: Excellent! write it up as an answer and accept it for the next person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution at wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan

Add an interface config file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` (or modify the global interface config file `/etc/network/interfaces`):

```
auto eth0 iface 
eth0 inet dhcp 
    ethernet-wol g
```

Activate it:

```
sudo reboot
```

It will only start working after the reboot and you shutdown.